# Congruence modulo p(x)

Tags: abstract-algebra

A theorem in the book I am using states

Let F be a field and p(x) a polynomial of degree n in F[X] and consider congruence modulo p(x).

Let S be the set consisting of the zero polynomial and all the polynomials of degree less than n in F[X]. Then every congruence class modulo p(x) is the class of some polynomial in S, and the congruence classes of different polynomials in S are distinct.

What I'm wondering is how you properly write out the set S for $\Bbb Q[X]$ modulo $x^2+2$. I see that it is infinite and understand what the set contains but I'm wondering if there is a systematic way to write it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe $\{ax+b \in \mathbb Q[X]\mid a,b\in \mathbb Q\}$

Comment: @dafinguzman thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\{ax+b \in \mathbb Q[X]\mid a,b\in \mathbb Q\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $I=\langle x^2+2\rangle>$ (ideal generated by $x^2+2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$), we have

$$\mathbb{Q}/I=\{(ax+b)+I\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$$

Note that if we denote elements of this quotient ring as $ax+b$ (suppressing $I$), we use the relation that $x^2=-2$ to reduce polynomials with powers of $x$ greater than or equal to $2$ to the $ax+b$ form.