# Implication of theorem about congruence modulo p(x)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-congruences

This question is related to this: [Congruence modulo p(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540686/congruence-modulo-px) and this [Congruence in F[x], proof involving infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248042/congruence-in-fx-proof-involving-infinity)

I'll just restate the theorem in question before my question:

Let $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ a polynomial of degree $n$ in $F[x]$, and consider congruence modulo $p(x)$.

1) If $f(x) \in F[x]$ and $r(x)$ is the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $p(x)$, then $[f(x)]=[r(x)]$.

2) Let $S$ be the set consisting of the zero polynomial and all the polynomials of degree less than $n$ in $F[x]$. Then every congruence class modulo $p(x)$ is the class of some polynomial in $S$, and the congruence classes of different polynomials in $S$ are distinct.

Here is the proof for 2):

Since $r(x)=0_{F}$ or $\text{ deg }r(x) < n$, we see that $r(x) \in S$. Hence, every congruence class is equal to the congruence class of a polynomial in $S$. Two different polynomials in $S$ cannot be congruent modulo $p(x)$ because their difference has degree less than $n$, and hence is not divisible by $p(x)$. Therefore, different polynomials in $S$ must be in distinct congruence classes since $f(x) \equiv g(x) (\text{mod} p(x))$ if and only if $[f(x)]=[g(x)].$

I am trying to understand exactly what the implications of 2) is. In the specific example of [Congruence in F[x], proof involving infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248042/congruence-in-fx-proof-involving-infinity) I try to show that there are infinitely many distinct congruence classes modulo $x^2 -2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Does it follow from 2) that there is a distinct congruence class for every polynomial in $S$? Or are there polynomials in $S$ which does not belong to some congruence class somehow?

I understand why every congruence class is equal to the congruence class of a polynomial in $S$, but do all congruence classes exhaust all the polynomials in $S$? I hope the question makes sense.

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but the more I think about this, the more I seem to be confusing myself. Any response is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: As an example to be more specific, could I argue using 2) that since every congruence class modulo $x^2-2$ is on the form $ax + b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then since there are infinitely many combinations of $a$ and $b$ there are infinitely many congruence classes? In my current understanding this would only work if it is the case that by 2) all polynomials in $S$ correspond to a different congruence class.

Comment: Congruence is an *equivalence relation*, q.v. So every element is in exactly one congruence class.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But does every polynomial in $S$ belong to a congruence class or does only every congruence class equal the congruence class of some polynomial in $S$ ? I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? **every element is in exactly one congruence class**

Comment: Do you not understand the meaning of "the congruence classes of different polynomials in S are distinct"?

Comment: So, are we all set now, Thomas?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I failed to explain what I wasn't sure about. Let me try a short explanation, because I think I understood your point, I just failed to adequately describe my confusion. My confusion was: How can we be sure that for any polynomial $r(x) = ax + b \in S$, where $a,b \in R$ there exists a polynomial $f(x)$ such that when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^2 - 2$ then $r(x)$ is the remainder. I think this follows from the division algorithm, since we could always pick any $r(x)$ and reverse engineer an $f(x)$, and this always works since $F$ is a field.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I understand both theorem and the proof in question fairly well at least, but when applied to the problem I described in the edit it was my impression that one would have to show that one could always find a polynomial $f(x)$ that was congruent to $r(x) = ax + b$ for any combination of $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.  I hope I was more clear this time. Thank you very much for your response :)

Comment: The polynomial $f(x)=ax+b$ leaves remainder $ax+b$ when divided by $x^2-2$.

Comment: So, are we all set now, Thomas?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, thank you Gerry :) Much appreciated.